# CamelCase regexp not accounting for spaces

Tags: ruby

I created a regexp to match the following scenerios: SomethingCool, HelloWorld, MyNameIsDonato, etc. However, it does not account for spaces:

```
> 'Something Cooler' =~ /([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)+/
 => 0
```

That passes and it should not pass. A space is not an alphanumeric character. So why does this pass and how can I fix it?

Comment: BTW, match here is `Something`, not the whole string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to anchor the regex to the beginning and end of the string, or it will just match one of the words:

```
^([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)+$
```

`^` and `$` anchor the beginnings and ends of lines, respectively. To anchor to the beginning and end of the string, use `\A` and `\Z`.

It's worth noting that this is useless if you're trying to find camelcase names within a larger string. For that, use your original regex.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. I will upvote your answer in 15 minutes.

Comment: Please always use `\A` and `\z` instead of `^` and `$` to prevent false matching of `"CamelCase\neval(`rm -rf /`)"`.

Comment: @mudasobwa: Depends on what you are doing. For one thing, that isn't a security hole unless you're evaling user input, at which point you need much better input sanitation, and most likely, a better approach. I usually use `\A` and `\Z`, but they seemed unnecessary here.

Comment: I was talking not about secuity hole, but about undebuggable positive match on `klazz = "CamelCase\n" ; klazz =~ regexp && const_get(klazz)` leading to an exception.

Comment: @mudasobwa: Mentioned `\A` and `\Z` in answer.

Comment: @mudasobwa: The inclusion of `eval("rm -rf /")` usually indicates someone is pointing out a security flaw. Sorry to have misinterpreted.

Comment: It turned out I have had this string in the buffer and just copy-pasted it, so all sorries are mine :)

Comment: You usually want `\z` and not `\Z` ([docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors)).